# Swap multiple variables in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, swap

Suppose three variables are

```
let x = 10, y = 20, z = 30;
```

and another three variables are

```
let a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

I want to swap these variable's value

Input is:

```
let x = 10, y = 20, z = 30;
let a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

output is:

```
let x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
let a = 10, b = 20, c = 30;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to swap variables:

```js
let x = 10, y = 20, z = 30
let a = 1, b = 2, c = 3

;[x, y, z, a, b, c] = [a, b, c, x, y, z]

console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}, z: ${z}, a: ${a}, b: ${b}, c: ${c}`)
```